# Solr StandardTokenizerFactory tokinize on dots filter

Tags: java, apache, solr, solrj

I wan't to search for certain numbers in my index but I'm having trouble with certain results. (I'm using edismax.)

Example:

```
    Term in index  I want to search: b1.123.456
    Query I use is b1 123 456 (no spaces)
```

This doesn't work because a . is not the same as a - (I've read the documentation)
I looked for a solution and found that I have to use a Filter on my field:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter  class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapchar.txt" />
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter  class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapchar.txt" />
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This is my fieldtype, the mapchar contains "."=>" "

Now when I try to search:

```
    b1.123.456   returns all results for each token (normal behaviour)
    "b1.123.456" returns what I'm looking for.
    "b1 123 456" returns what I'm looking for.
     b1 123 456  **returns nothing**
```

**Why does a normal edismax query without phrase search return 0 results?**

Edit:

I've found an error in the logs when I use the last query:

```
<record>
  <date>2012</date>
  <millis></millis>
  <sequence></sequence>
  <logger>org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter</logger>
  <level>SEVERE</level>
  <class>org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</class>
  <method>log</method>
  <thread>12</thread>
  <message>null:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.util.SolrPluginUtils.calculateMinShouldMatch(SolrPluginUtils.java:563)
    at org.apache.solr.util.SolrPluginUtils.setMinShouldMatch(SolrPluginUtils.java:518)
    at org.apache.solr.search.ExtendedDismaxQParser.parse(ExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin.java:264)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:185)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1699)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:455)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:276)
    at ...
</message>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the default query handler worked(/select) I started to think something was wrong with my query handler.

To find out what was wrong I started disabling parts of my own request handler a bit.

```
  <!--<str name="mm"></str>-->
```

An **empty mm** can give you **errors**!

I used to have an mm parameter but I diden't really needed it anymore so I left it empty...